# Show that ${n+1 \choose r+1}={n \choose r}+{n \choose r+1}$, from a more intuitive sense

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From a more intuitive sense, why the following formula is true? 
$${n+1 \choose r+1}={n \choose r}+{n \choose r+1}$$

Although I can prove the above formula by using ${n \choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, but the following explanation makes no sense to me:

> Let **A** be a **set** containing ***n+1*** elements, and suppose
>   $x\in A$. The left side of above formula counts the number of
>   **(r+1)-element** subsets of **A**. We can separate these subsets into two groups:
>
> (1) those **containing** x, and (2) those **not containing** x.
>
> If **x is in the subset**, then we must select **r** other elements
>   from the remaining n elements of **A** to form an (r+1)-element
>   subset. There are ${n \choose r}$ ways of choosing these r elements.
>
> If **x is not in the subset**, we must select **r+1** elements from
>   the remaining n elements of A. There are ${n \choose r+1}$ ways of
>   choosing these elements.
>
> Thus, the number of (r+1)-element subsets from the (n+1)-element set A
>   equals the number of (r+1)-element subsets **containing x** plus the
>   number of (r+1)-element subsets **not containing x**.

So, in the cases of **x is in the subset**, and **x is not in the subset**, how do we obtain ${n \choose r}$ and ${n \choose r+1}$?

Above quoted explanation sounds confusing to me. What are the "*remaining n elements*"? Don't we have n+1 elements in this case, how can we choose **r+1** elements from **n**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be seen really simply by replacing all of the variables with small numbers.

$\binom{5}{3}=10$ is the number of 3 element subsets of {1,2,3,4,5}.  Ten isn't too many, so let's list them: {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,5}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,5}, {3,4,5}.

Now, let's split them into two different categories: those that contain 5 and those that don't.

- The second category is {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {2,3,4}.  Clearly those are just the 3 element subsets of {1,2,3,4}, so there are $\binom{4}{3}$ of them.
- The first category is {1,2,5}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,5}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,5}, {3,4,5}.  If you think about it, those are all of the 2 element subsets of {1,2,3,4} combined with the singleton {5}.  Since there is a one-to-one correspondence there, there must be $\binom{4}{2}$ of those.

Since we have accounted for every 3 element subset of {1,2,3,4,5} exactly once, we have demonstrated that $\binom{5}{3}=\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

A size-$r+1$ subset $S$ of $A$ is said to *own* those $y$ for which $y\in S$. Then $S$ is specified by identifying which $r$ elements of $A\setminus\{x\}$ it owns if $x\in S$, or which $r+1$ elements of $A\setminus\{x\}$ it owns if $x\not\in S$. The former case comprises $\binom{|A\setminus\{x\}|}{r}=\binom{|A|-1}{r}=\binom{n}{r}$ choices for $S$, the latter $\binom{n}{r+1}$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the "*remaining n elements*"?

That are all elements of $A$ that *differ* from $x\in A$.

You could say that $A=B\cup\{x\}$ where $B$ has $n$ elements that all differ from $x$.

There are $\binom{n}{r}$ subsets of $B$ that contain exactly $r$ elements and each of these sets induces a subset of $A$ that contains $r+1$ elements by adding $x$ as element to that set (so any set $C\subseteq B$ with $|C|=r$ induces set $C\cup\{x\}\subseteq A$).

Further there are $\binom{n}{r+1}$ subsets of $B$ that contain exactly $r+1$ elements and they are also subsets of $A$ (so any set $C\subseteq B$ with $|C|=r+1$ induces set $C\subseteq A$).

Each subset of $A$ that contains exactly $r+1$ elements belongs to one of the sort so that $$\binom{n+1}{r+1}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$I hope this spreads some light.